# How to show warning message when back button is pressed in fragments

Tags: android, android-navigation-editor

I want application to show warning message when user press back button and if user select Yes it will go back. And i am in navigation graph fragment.

I have searched many time in stack Overflow and tried:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle("Save Or Not");
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to save this? ");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            /*Go back:-I dont know how*/
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Discard",null);
    builder.show();
}
```

But it is showing giver error:
**Method does not override method from its superclass**

Edit:
I want to set onBackPressedListener(Mobiles back button) in Navigation graphs fragment

Comment: Add boolean variable isBack = false and if it say yes make it true and check the condition that isBack is false or true and if it is true add super.pressBack() else show the alter dialog

wrap the alter dialog in different function

Comment: You Want to get back button from the fragment. ?

Comment: I need to  onBackButtonClickListener- In Navigation graph fragment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Fragments 1.1.0 (which is in alpha right now), you can follow the [Provide custom back navigation documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back), which shows how to register an [`OnBackPressedCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedCallback), which allows you to register for `onBackPressed()` callbacks from within a Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // This callback will only be called when MyFragment is at least Started.
    OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true /* enabled by default */) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            builder.setTitle("Save Or Not");
            builder.setMessage("Do you want to save this? ");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // Save your content
                save();
                // Then pop
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(MyFragment.this).popBackStack();
            }
            builder.setNegativeButton("Discard",null);
            builder.show();
        });
        }
    });
    requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have version 1.0.0-beta02 fragment version in gradel. Can changing it from gradel to 1.1.0 update its version

Comment: Note the "requireActivity()" prefix above is needed when the OnBackPressedDispatcher is set up from within a Fragment but the prefix is not needed when setting up from within an Activity.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line in button clicklistner `MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();`
Replace your Activity name insted of `MainActivity`

```
 builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
          dialog.dismiss();
          MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
         //Replace your Activity name insted of MainActivity
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for help  but i am in android navigation graph fragment and when i type CreateGame.super.onBackPressed(); it cannot resolve it(i have also done getActivity())

Comment: Android studio is not resolving .onBackPressed() in extends fragment

Comment: onbackpress is only for Activity not in Fragment , use onbackpress for that Fragment in their parent Activity

Comment: oh sad to hear that. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   //Replace Your Own Action Like Adding Toast etc and Also SuperOnbackprssed or any overriden method
                    dialog.cancel();

                }
            });
```